# Creating chatbot using chatterbot

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I have installed chatterbot and now I am running a file using it but I am facing following error.....

> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a
>   shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Please help me to fix this.

code is as following....

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer


chatbot = ChatBot("Ron Obvious")



conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train(conversation)

response = chatbot.get_response("Good morning!")
print(response)
```

Comment: @Mohammad Rabiulla thanks for editing my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to download the required packages

try this

`python -m spacy download en`

Comment: I am having the same trouble and I downloaded the required packages as you said, however I am getting `Creating a shortcut link for 'en' didn't work (maybe you don't have admin permissions?)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, while opening the Anaconda Prompt, right-click on it and run as administrator and then try

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

for linking `en_core_web_sm` to `en`, follow this command

```
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en
```

This shall resolve both errors.